Add two diagonal lines on top of y-axis ranging outside plot area to highlight truncation
I have a bar plot using ggplot() in which I have truncated the y-axis using coord_cartesian() so that differenes between the bars are more easily visible. In other words, the y-axis does not start at 0. I want to highlight this adjustment by adding two parallel diagonal lines in the lower end of the y-axis. How can I add these so that they are visible even in the negative quadrant?
Edit: Added snippet of data as well as example of what the result should look like:
  Trialcount Stimulus.ACC    N Stimulus.RT       sd        se        ci
1          1            0 1597    792.5792 310.2690  7.764008  15.22872
2          2            1   47   1061.4043 477.0400 69.583435 140.06419
3          3            0 1019    929.4210 385.5723 12.078659  23.70192
4          4            1  918    910.0447 373.0941 12.313941  24.16678
5          5            0  278   1115.7986 447.2075 26.821723  52.80031
6          6            1 1655    861.1704 342.7538  8.425260  16.52530
7          7            0 1019    929.4210 385.5723 12.078659  23.70192

Above data snippet as a tibble in R:
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(papaja)

rt_val_summary <- tibble(
  Trialcount = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  Stimulus.ACC = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  N = c(1597, 47, 1019, 918, 278, 1655, 1019),
  Stimulus.RT = c(792.5792, 1061.4043, 929.4210, 910.0447, 1115.7986, 861.1704, 929.4210),
  sd = c(310.2690, 477.0400, 385.5723, 373.0941, 447.2075, 342.7538, 385.5723),
  se = c(7.764008, 69.583435, 12.078659, 12.313941, 26.821723, 8.425260, 12.078659),
  ci = c(15.22872, 140.06419, 23.70192, 24.16678, 52.80031, 16.52530, 23.70192)
)

This is the plot so far:
RT_val_plot <- ggplot(data=rt_val_summary, aes(x=Trialcount, y = Stimulus.RT, fill = factor(Stimulus.ACC))) +
geom_bar(stat = "summary", position="dodge") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) +
labs(x = "Trial", y = "Reaction time (ms)") +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(300, 1200)) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "green", "red", "green", "red", "green", "red", "green", "red", "green", "red", "green", "red", "green"),
name = "Valence", labels = c("negative", "positive")) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Stimulus.RT-se, ymax=Stimulus.RT+se), width =.1, position=position_dodge(.9)) +
geom_text(aes(label=paste("n =", N)), vjust=-0.5, position=position_dodge(0.9), size=3) +
geom_point(size = 2 , position=position_dodge(.9)) +
theme_apa()

And the following is a very raw, hand-drawn example of what my result should look like:

I tried different methods, e.g. adding lines using geom_segment() or annotation_custom() but these were only visible in the plot area (x&y>0). When setting clip=off in coord_cartesian(), this makes the bar plots visible in the area with y<0 as well, which I want to avoid

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data shared using dput() (or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset).

Instead of truncating your bars using coord_cartesian you might consider using a geom_rect to draw your bars where you set the start according to the lower limit.

Do consider that bars that do not start at 0 are often misleading, as people are naturally inclined to interpret the ratio of bar lengths as the ratio of magnitudes. I don't know what the "negative quadrant" is, as all your values appear to be positive.

@stefan what advantage would geom_rect give me over coord_cartesian?

@AxemanThat's right and the reason I want to mark this in the plot. The absolute values of my data are not as important as the differences. All my data are negative, but the added diagonal lines are supposed to be outside of this range to some extent

As I already mentioned in my comment one option would be to use a geom_rect which allows to limit the lower end of bars to the panel border. Hence, when setting clip="off" the bars will not reach beyond the panel border:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = rt_val_summary, aes(x = Trialcount, y = Stimulus.RT, fill = factor(Stimulus.ACC))) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = after_stat(x - .45), xmax = after_stat(x + .45),
      ymin = after_stat(-Inf), ymax = after_stat(y)
    ),
    stat = "summary", position = "dodge"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 1:7,
    expand = expansion(add = .5)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = expansion(add = c(0, .5))
  ) +
  labs(x = "Trial", y = "Reaction time (ms)") +
  coord_cartesian(
    xlim = c(0.5, 7.5),
    ylim = c(300, 1200),
    clip = "off"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("red", "green"),
    name = "Valence",
    labels = c("negative", "positive")
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = Stimulus.RT - se, ymax = Stimulus.RT + se),
    width = .1, position = position_dodge(.9)
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste("n =", N)),
    vjust = -0.5,
    position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3
  ) +
  geom_point(size = 2, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  annotate(
    geom = "segment",
    x = -.25, xend = .25,
    y = c(280, 300), yend = c(320, 340),
    color = "black"
  )
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`


